# Using calc() in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Objective:

To create **two divs, side-by-side on a page**. Together they should cover 100% of the page. using latest versions of *react + Material UI*.

**div on the left should have a fixed width (say 200px).**

**div on the right should cover the rest of the page.**

In CSS, one could use calc(100% - 200px) to dynamically compute the width of div on the right.

Issue Faced:

I couldn't use that in Material UI. I tried inline styling ( `style={{width='calc(100%-200)'}}`), which compiles but doesn't work. I also tried `makeStyles()`, but with no avail.

I deeply appreciate the community's help in this matter.

Comment: You need `200px` instead of just `200`.

Answer (score 25):

For anyone curious about how to write this using `makeStyles()`:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  width: 'calc(100% - 200px)'
});
```

Or if the pixel amount is dynamically generated in the javascript layer:

```js
const elWidth = getMyElementWidth(); // returns '200'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  width: `calc(100% - ${elWidth}px)`
});
```

The main issue, as [dlewiski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936445/129086) points out, is the need to include spaces around the operator and to include the `px` unit.

I've often made the "forgetting to include spaces around the operator inside `calc()`" mistake.

Comment: ahh.. yes! because all values in makeStyles need to be proper javascript values, strings..  
To make it clear for others doing inlines this is an example using theme.spacing, where I have a Paper component in a container and due to padding and margins need it to behave according to their spacing, so I take the full height minus spacing of the margins (top and bottom). ::::: 
outerPaper: {
        margin: theme.spacing(5),
        height: `calc(100% - ${theme.spacing(10)}px)`,   
    }

Answer (score 15):

I just want to point out that the key issues I see is no spaces between the '-' and no 'px' after 200.

So you have `style={{width='calc(100%-200)'}}`

Should be `style={{width='calc(100% - 200px)'}}`

I realize this is already shown in the original answer but I thought some more clarification on the specifics of the issue would help.

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying. As someone who's learning css and makeStyles, I was scratching my head over this for hours.

Answer (score 10):

If your code doesn't work anymore in **MUI v5**, check if you're using `theme.spacing()` because there is a breaking change in the newer version. From the [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#theme-structure):

> `theme.spacing` now returns single values with `px` units by default.

Correct code in:

**V5**

```
width: `calc(100vw - ${theme.spacing(3)})`
```

**V4**

```
width: `calc(100vw - ${theme.spacing(3)}px)`
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 3):

since style is an object you can't use =.

the right way to do it:

> style={{width: 'calc(100% - 200px)'}}

if not applied, try

> style={{width: 'calc(100% - 200px) !important'}}

Comment: I guess it is worth to include the `calc()` documentation as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Thanks @get2dachoppa.